# Edit Gcode to change all G1 Z

Tags: notepad++, sublime-text-3

I need to edit a standard but very long Gcode from Simplify3D and get a new Gcode with all G1 Zvalue set to 100 for testing purpose.

I am trying with sublime text editor to find Z and replace with Z100 but when the program find Z4 it then becomes z1004.

Example:

```
G1 Z170.520 F6000
```

has to become:

```
G1 Z100 F6000
```

thx!

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `Z\S+`
- Replace with: `Z100`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
Z           # letter Z
\S+         # 1 or more non-space character
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: thank you! it works

Comment: @PatrykPabo: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).